# How To Set up a UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, uipageviewcontroller

I have been looking for tutorials regarding the setup of a UIPageViewController because somebody recommended not using my navigational controller but instead to use the PageView. I am using the swipe gesture left and right as well but I am yet to find a good tutorial online in regards to the setup of the UIPageViewController via storyboard (or at least majority storyboard).

I included a picture of what I am working with at the moment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eNzE.jpg

Any help in regards to the setup of the PageViewController and then following controllers would be much appreciated!

Thank you for your help in advanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure you can find some tutorials out there if you Google it, but this should give you a start trying your own implementation. I created a new project starting from the "Page-Base Application" template. You should study the code that gives you to try to understand what it does (along with reading Apple's documentation on UIPageViewController).

That project creates several objects. The RootViewController creates the page view controller and adds it as a child view controller. For my test app, I didn't change anything in this file other than changing the transition style of the page view controller to UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll (instead of page curl, but you should try the original value too to see what it looks like).

The ModelController class contains the model, which in your case would be an array of image names (or pieces of the name as I have). This class implements the page view controller data source methods that handle the turning of the pages. I changed the init method in that class to this,

```
- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _pageData = @[@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5", @"6"]; // my images are named img1.JPG, img2.JPG, etc. I will use these numbers to construct the path to my files in the bundle
    }
    return self;
}
```

So, you can see that the model is just an array of number strings (one number for each image). You might have to try something different depending on how your images are named. When you swipe between pages, the index into this array is either incremented or decremented, and the value in the array is passed to the DataViewController into its dataObject property.

The DataViewController is the controller that actually shows your content. It's the right controller in the storyboard. I modified its view by adding a navigation bar at the top so we can put in a title and button (to go to your tips view controllers), and replaced the UIView subview with a UIImageView that takes up the whole screen under the navigation bar. I made IBOutlets to the image view and the navigation bar. Here is the changed .h file for that controller,

```
@interface DataViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString  *dataObject;
```

Finally, in the .m file, I made it look like this,

```
@interface DataViewController ()
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UINavigationBar *bar;
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *iv;
@end

@implementation DataViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UINavigationItem *titleItem = self.bar.items[0];
    titleItem.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Course Guide %@",self.dataObject];
    NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"img%@", self.dataObject] ofType:@"JPG"];
    self.iv.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
}

-(void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"in dealloc");
}
```

I'm using initWithContentsOfFile: to create the images (rather than imageNamed: because it doesn't cache the images) based on the number that's passed in to the dataObject. I implemented dealloc to illustrate the fact that as you swipe back and forth through the pages, the controllers are deallocated, thus keeping your memory footprint small. If the transition style is page curl, the controllers are deallocated as soon as they go off screen, so there's never more than one in existence at a time. If the style is scroll, then there are 3 in existence at a time, because the page view controller creates the current one as well as the previous and next ones to make the loading faster.

As you can see, I've made only a few small changes to the code the template gives you, in order to display an array of images which should suit your purpose. A structure such as this for your app will be much more memory efficient than using a stack of controllers in a navigation controller.

Comment: Thank you for your in-depth answer. Much appreciated. In your 'test app,' did you create two Objective-C Classes one named: DataViewController (a sub class of the UIViewController) and the other named ModelViewController (a sub class of the UIViewController as well)? I understand the majority of the code except the locations in which to put it. For example you mention the init method. Should the init method go in the default viewcontroller.m or one of the new classes you mentioned? Same goes for the last two blocks of code as well.

Comment: @user3743364, I didn't create any new classes, all the objects are already created in the template. If you look at the paragraph right above that first block of code, it states that the code is in the ModelController. As for the other code, you can see the name of the class, DataViewController, right in the code. I used Xcode 5.1 to create this app, and all the code, except for my minor changes, is in the template.

Comment: I recreated each snippet of code putting the (id)init in the default template viewcontroller.m, the second block of code in the viewcontroller.h as mentioned, and the final, again, in the viewcontroller.m as well. I connected the navigation bar and the image view up top with the IBOutlet and everything seemed a go. Xcode says: "Use of Undeclared identifier '_pageData' and I am not quite sure how to fix: http://imgur.com/3QLrj8v Also, if my images are named (lets say) golf1.png, golf2.png, golf3.png, etc... How would I implement those names into the .m file as you did with @"1",@"2"etc

Comment: @user3743364 what template are you starting with, and what version of Xcode are you using? Those are not the right classes.

Comment: I am using Xcode 5.1.1 and I am using the single view application with storyboard

Comment: @user3743364, as I said in my answer, you should be starting with the "Page-Based" template. That one has all the classes I mentioned in my post.

Comment: If I already have a massive Xcode file started from the single view application, how can I still implement the page-based elements/template?

Comment: @user3743364, you could copy the files over from the page-based template into your project, and change your storyboard to add the controllers that the template uses.

Comment: Alright everything sounds good and I am finally starting to get somewhere. To test out the code you put above, I created a new template and found all of the proper controllers etc.. The Course Guide 1, 2, 3 etc works up top but the image I connected to the IBOutlet doesn't seem to change. I included a screenshot of the two controllers that deal with the name of the images. I changed .jpg to .png and I changed the 1, 2, 3 etc that you had to Golf1, Golf2, etc because thats the name of my images. For some reason though, no images show up when I run the program: http://imgur.com/3Y0B7ps

Comment: @user3743364, look at what you're passing to pathForResource:ofType: in the viewDidLoad method in the DataViewController. You need to make that work with what your array is.

Comment: I recreated the page view in a separate project but the problem comes when I bring those files (.h and .m files) over and then connect everything. I made a video here: https://vidd.me/FTH Originally, I didn't get the error shown in the video and just got a (null) in the navigation up top and no image showing, then I Was able to get the top working but not the images, and now I am running into this error. I think once I get past this, I should be able to get it working in the main application. I just want to thank you again for helping me out with this your help is much appreciated.

Comment: @user3743364, the error is saying that DataViewController doesn't have a key called "mybar". So somewhere in the storyboard you've used "mybar", but the name of the property in the class is "bar". I also noticed that you have a breakpoint set (the blue rectangle with a point) next to the line where you declare the property for bar at the top of the DataViewController .m file. You should drag that off to the left to get rid of it.

Comment: Ok so I fixed the crashing and it is now going back to the same (null) it seemed to have gone to before: https://vidd.me/UaY

Comment: @user3743364, it's not easy for me to debug your program from a video -- you need to do some debugging on your own. For instance, in DataViewController, at the end of the viewDidLoad method, put in logs for self.dataObject and self.iv.image to see if either or both have the correct values.

Comment: If you can't tell, Im new to Xcode and iOS programming. How do I input logs? I haven't worked with logs yet but I am willing to learn!

Comment: @user3743364, NSLog(@"%@", self.dataObject) and NSLog(@"%@", self.iv.image), and get yourself a good objective-c book because you really need to learn some basics.

Comment: Inputted each of the NSLogs under dataviewcontroller.m inside the viewdidload method as you mentioned. http://imgur.com/2VtOWjd

Comment: @user3743364, sorry, I can't troubleshoot your app from afar. If you'd like to hire me to write your program, I'm available. Otherwise, you need to spend the time to learn objective-c and the cocoa touch framework. It takes a good deal of time and effort, but if you want to write good apps, that's what you have to do.

Comment: I have actually been looking for a developer for a couple parts of the app I have been working on. I recently hired a company in India and that turned out poorly and I lost a good $330 for absolutely nothing and since then, I have been looking for a trusty developer. Do you have a Skype or email in which we could communicate?

Comment: @user3743364, my email is rdelmar@comcast.net

Comment: I ran into another little bug. I am not sure if your email notifications are working so I'm figured I would comment and let you know.